# Use haproxy to redirect when 404 from the backend

Tags: haproxy

I'm using haproxy 1.5.18 and it does SSL termination and redirect to various backends using ACLs.

I would like to redirect the user (302) to a different page if the backend returns a 404.  What's the best way to do this ?

I have found a [thread dating 2009](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/912) and solves the problem using rsprep. Is it still the way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have something that work.

Any better option are welcome.

```
   frontend fe
        bind 0.0.0.0:81
        use_backend be
backend be
         mode http
         acl not_found               status 404
         rsprep ^HTTP/1.1\ 404\ (.*)$ HTTP/1.1\ 302\ Found\nLocation:\ / if not_found
         server server1 127.0.0.1:80 check
```

Answer (score 2):

```
frontend fe
  acl not_found status 404
  http-response set-header Location https://google.com/ if not_found
  http-response set-status 302 if not_found
```

It seems the `http-response redirect` syntax worked in haproxy 1.8, but in ubuntu builds we use it fails in 1.9 in a weird manner, and doesn't work at all in 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
listen fe
  bind 0.0.0.0:82
  acl not_found status 404
  http-response redirect code 302 location https://google.fr if not_found
  server server1 127.0.0.1:80 check
```